Regular Perturbation for ODE with both x and y
The problem
$$ y'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2} y (y - 1)}{x}, \quad y(0) = 1 $$
Has the trivial solution of $y^{trivial}\equiv1$. However, it has another solution $y(x)\not\equiv y^{trivial}$.
Find a three-term series expansion of $y(x)$ for $0<x\ll1$.
Attempts

Assuming series expansion
$$ y(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n $$
derivating, substituting to both sides of the original equation and comparing coefficients gives
$$ a_1 = \sqrt{2}a_1 $$
Which means $a_1=0$. So, this seems like a dead-end.
Trying to apply Successive Approximation seems to require some-kind of arrangement of the equation into the form of:
$$ F(x)=G(x) $$
But this will require removing $y$, which seems rather complicated in this case.

Questions

Did I miss any step in the Series Expansion method?
Is there any other, more appropriate method?


Your and my mistake was to use an expansion in $x^n$ instead of $x^{n\sqrt 2}$

@ClaudeLeibovici I actually did assume a non-natural power in my second attempt.

I don't see it Where is it written ? Cheers and thanks for an interestin problem

Oh, sorry, I did not elaborate in the question that my second attempt was Successive Approximation mainly because it does not assume natural power of x. I actually played with guessing solutions (nice game) and realized it should have $\sqrt 2$ somewhere in the power because we have y' on the left and $\sqrt 2$ on the right. Not sure those insights are critical. BTW, there's a close term, elegant solution $\frac{1}{1-C*x^{\sqrt{2}}}$. It has the same Taylor series.
Glad you enjoyed the problem! Will try to post more :)

Since you reach a contradiction with your expansion, it's a sign your other solutions are not expressible as an integer power series in $x$.  To find out what else they could be, let $y = 1+v$, then
$$
xv' = \sqrt 2 v(v+1) \sim \sqrt 2 v, \qquad v \ll 1
$$
so that the leading order term in $v$ is the solution to $xv' = \sqrt 2 v$, or $v \sim Cx^{\sqrt 2}$ for any $C$.
Now to find a third term, let $y = 1 + Cx^{\sqrt 2} + w$, then
$$
xw' + \sqrt 2Cx^\sqrt{2} = \sqrt 2(1+Cx^\sqrt{2} + w)(Cx^{\sqrt{2}} + w).
$$
The dominant terms are
$$
xw' \sim \sqrt 2 w + \sqrt 2 Cx^{2\sqrt 2},
$$
the particular solution of which is $w \sim Cx^{2\sqrt 2}$.  Thus
$$
y = 1 + Cx^{\sqrt 2} + Cx^{2\sqrt 2} + \ldots
$$
for any $C$.

You are very correct.
Taking more than one term, such as
$$y(x) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{3} a_n x^n$$ and replacing, we have
$$0=\sqrt{2} a_1^2+\sqrt{2} \left(a_1^3+3 a_2
   a_1\right) x+2 \sqrt{2} \left(2 a_2 a_1^2+2
   a_3 a_1+a_2^2\right) x^2+$$ $$5 \sqrt{2}
   \left(a_3 a_1^2+a_2^2 a_1+a_2 a_3\right)
   x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So, successively, $$a_1=0 \implies a_2=0 \implies a_3=0$$ and so on.
Edit
The solution of
$$y' = \frac{\sqrt{2}\, y\, (y - 1)}{x} \qquad \text{with}\qquad y(a) = b$$is given by
$$y(a,b)=\frac{a^{\sqrt{2}}\, b}{a^{\sqrt{2}}\, b+(1-b)\, x^{\sqrt{2}}}$$ Then, $\forall a~~y(a,1)=1$ and $\forall b~~y(0,b)=0$
Update
$$y=\frac{a^{\sqrt{2}}\, b}{a^{\sqrt{2}}\, b+(1-b)\, x^{\sqrt{2}}}\quad \implies \quad y=\frac 1 {1+ k \,x^{\sqrt{2}}}$$ which satisfies the condition $y(0)=1$ without its introduction in the problem.
Using @messenger's idea, let $t=x^{\sqrt{2}}$ to make the equation
$$t\,y'-y(y-1)=0$$ (which gives again the same solution $y=\frac 1 {1+k t}$) and let
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,t^n$$ wich gives by identification of the coefficients
$$a_0=1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\, a_1^n$$ and the infinite summation gives the same result $y=\frac{1}{1+a(1) t}$.
All of the above confirm the solution
$$\large\color{blue}{y=\frac 1 {1+ k \,x^{\sqrt{2}}}}$$
Nota
If we let $x=t^a$, the equation write
$$t^{-a}\Big(\frac t a y'-\sqrt 2 y(y-1) \Big)=0$$ and its simpl simples form corresponds to $a=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}$; so $t=x^{{\sqrt 2}}$.

Thanks, but I know for sure that there is another solution, where $y(x)\not\equiv 1$. So, there should be another method to find this other solution(s).

@Michael. Have a look at the edit

does the edit yield any new solutions for the given a=0, b=1?
There's another answer here that does yield a new solution for the given boundary condition.
